# Fineuploader file is empty validation fires in safari for multiple files

Tags: fine-uploader

The file is empty built-in validation fires when multiple files are selected in safari. I was able to duplicate this behaviour in the fine uploader demo site. Steps to reproduce:

1. Start safari (I have tried windows desktop safari, iPad and iPhone)
2. go to http://fineuploader.com/demos.html
3. Click the Upload files button under the text restrictions to jpeg, jpg and txt
4. Select multiple jpg files.
5. The file is empty validation error appears.

This does not happen if the files are chosen individual or if using IE or Chrome.

Comment: Flagged as off-topic: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

Comment: This is a programming issue. I hoping there are options in the fine uploader javascript library to get around this issue.

Comment: Check this link on [issue tracker](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1239) related to Safari. I hope you may not need this request anymore.

Comment: Though [Browser Support Page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/browser-support.html) says Mobile Safari on iPhone and iPad are supported

Comment: Stsck overflow is not a bug tracker. If you feel you have found a bug, please file it in the project issue tracker. When you do, you'll need to include useful information as well, such as the fine Uploader version, iOS version, etc.

Comment: If this is an issue with Windows Safari, note that Windows Safari has never been supported and never will be supported as Windows Safari is a dead browser. If you are using Windows Safari, I would suggest finding a new browser. It's not very clear from your question which OS you are referring to, but it sounds like you are using Windows Safari.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did not realize that windows safari was not support. Sorry about that.